# IIS 7 NT Authencation fail Redirect

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, iis-7

On IIS 7 i have NT auth for the site. In AD I have users and they belong to groups. In ASP.NET applicaiton i neeed to allows only certain groups not every one AD. Is there any way at IIS level i can restrict the access to certain groups for the site? Or each page I have to check that user is valid or not?

Also i need to redirect to differnt page if the user is not part of any group? or on AD? How do is do that in IIS 7

Comment: PS: You may get more answers if you accept more answers to previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @user171523 A couple questions for you but I have some answers too. Have you seen this book? It can walk you through the material for what you're wanting to do.

[http://www.amazon.com/ASP-NET-2-0-Unleashed-Stephen-Walther/dp/0672328232](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328232)

What resources have you seen already? Will MSDN be able to help you, or do you need some walkthroughs? Will you be configuring this by hand or automagically? Will you be using the ASP.NET tool included via VS or will you need to code something by hand?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Custon401Page.aspx

With the help of Applcation_EndRequest event you can handle this.